Kahler-Ricci flow on Fano manifolds with initial metric not in the first Chern class
Let $\omega(t)$ be a normalized Kahler-Ricci flow Fano manifold $M$, i.e.
$$\partial_{t}\omega=-Ric+\omega.$$
Suppose $\chi\in c_{1}(M)$ is a Kahler metric, and $\Omega$ is a volume form on $M$ such that $-\partial\bar{\partial}\log\Omega=\chi$, then
$$[\omega(t)]=e^{t}([\omega_{0}]-[\chi])+[\chi],$$
The KRF equation is equivalent to the parabolic Monge-Ampere equation
$$\partial_{t}\varphi=\log\frac{\omega^{n}(t)}{\Omega}+\varphi+\beta(t),$$
where
$$\omega(t)=e^{t}(\omega_{0}-\chi)+\chi+\sqrt{-1}\partial\bar{\partial}\varphi$$
and $\beta(t)$ is a normalizing term.
When $\omega_{0}\in c_{1}(M)$, and we chose $\omega_{0}=\chi$, we have some good estimates of the flow, such as Perelman's diameter estimates. Moreover, if $M$ admits a Kahler-Einstein metric, then $\omega(t)$ will converge to the KE metric. But when $\omega_{0}\notin c_{1}(M)$, things become complicated. My question is:

The diameter estimate does not hold anymore. For example, we can consider the cross product $\mathbb{CP}^{1}\times\mathbb{CP}^{1}$ of two spheres with different radius. But I think there is still some hope that we have some estimates for the potential $\varphi$. Are there such estimates?
If $\omega_{0}-\chi$ is semi-positive, then the flow exists on $[0,+\infty)$. As $t\rightarrow\infty$, $[\omega(t)]$ does not converge, hence we cannot have convergence of $\omega(t)$. But can we have convergence of, for example, $e^{-t}\omega(t)$?

In fact, any reference about KRF on Fano manifolds with unnormalized initial metric would be appreciated. Thanks!
